# How to add hour/min/sec to epoch time from command line

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am fetching the current EPOCH time of my VM by using `date  +%s%3N` (including milli sec as well). Is there a way we can add hr or min or sec (to retrieve the future time) to current epoch time and retrieve it from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, do as following to adding an hour to the current EPOCH (Using GNU date):

```
date -d'+1hour' +%s%3N
```

or adding an hour and 10 minutes and 20seconds

```
date -d'+1hour +10minutes +20seconds' +%s%3N
```

or add all in seconds (1hour+10min+20sec=4220sec):

```
date -d'+4220seconds' +%s%3N
```